# OpenLayers Scaleline always wrong in my virtual star map

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers-2, scale, geoext

I got a problem for the scale line when I using OpenLayers to show my "star map".

Basically, I give a set of 2D coordinates (X,Y) for each star, and generate the map using MapServer.  Now the map can be correctly shown, but when I add scaleline control, I found the scaleline always starts at 500000000KM which is not correct. The correct scale should be 5400KM, which if I directly use MapServer CGI, it show correctly.

Hope anyone can help me out.

Here is map file:

```
MAP
    NAME "starmap1"
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4326"
    END
    UNITS meters
    IMAGETYPE PNG
    EXTENT -31230139.51 -8267352.329 36978851.96 9060799.858
    SIZE 800 600`
```

Here is my JavaScript (using GeoExt):

```
panel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
    renderTo: "mappanel",
    map: { maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-31230139.510000,-25170977.043091,
        36978851.960000,25964424.572091),  
        maxResolution: 85367.949274,
        numZoomLevels:40} ,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        floating: true,
        x: 70,
        y: 350
    });

panel.map.zoomToMaxExtent();
panel.map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine());
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem you have came up against is about projection problem. you can modify it when adding this to your `mapOptions`:

```
projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913'),
displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326')
```

if you change them with each other, you can get 100.000 times greater result..

i hope it helps you....

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I tried to add two options above, but mapserver return error msg "SRS must valid for all request layer" . Can I ask why you suggest to project EPSG:900913 , but my mapfile using epsg:4326? Sorry, I am a newbie in this field.

Comment: it calculates the scale line with metric way. ok if it is problem, get olControlScaleLine class element and divide it to 100.000 for real result...

Comment: I notice the error because no definition for 900913 in /usr/share/proj/epsg file. I add the definition, and error disappears.  And I try to change my mapfile "PROJECTION "init=epsg:900913" END ", the map can show correctly, but scaleline still the same as the old version, and the scale are not correct.  Need more help... thank you

Comment: I think now the scale is 100000 times more than the real one.

Comment: Dear Aragon,  can you tell how to "get olControlScaleLine class element and divide it to 100.000 for real result..."? I know I can get the value in this way: var sl=new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(); alert(sl.div.firstChild.innerHTML);

Comment: did you try above code which i gave after changing of mapfile `"PROJECTION "init=epsg:900913" END "`

Comment: yes, I tried, still 100000 times bigger than the real one. I changed `init=epsg:900913` in the mapfile, and added `map: { maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-48586319.220000,-34384434.301227,53085639.920000,41837722.801227),  maxResolution: 127249.010188,numZoomLevels:40,projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913'),
displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326')},` in my javascript.